# skimage watershed segmentation for lung image segmentation

Tags: python-3.x, image-segmentation, scikit-image, watershed

I am getting some kind of noise or unintended output from skimage.segmentation.watershed(). I am new to image processing so I don't know about other parameters of watershed().

After that when I use mark_boundaries() the same output is reflected over there too.

It would be helpful if anyone knows how to remove that dots from segmented image.

here are my code and outputs

1. mask

   plt.imshow(binarye, cmap="gray")

[image]

2. The image on which I want perform segmentation
   [image]
3. output image

   segments_watershed = watershed(img_one, 1000, mask=binarye)
   plt.imshow(segments_watershed, cmap="gray")
   [image]

Comment: That looks like a bug in how the mask and seeds interact. Could you please raise an issue on github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image/issues ? Please include your example image in raw form and the code required to get to the watershed result? Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is fixed.

[Gitgub issue page](https://github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image/issues/3808)

[Github solution](https://github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image/pull/3809)